# How to do an incremental build with distutils in python 2.7?

Tags: python, build, python-2.7, distutils, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.7 distutils to build a C++ library. However every time I issue the build command with

```
python setup.py build
```

all object files are built again, even though the c++-file did not change.
A friend of mine told me that this would not be the case for Python 2.6.

My questions to this board:

1. Is there a way to force distutils to incrementally build the code?
2. If it is not possible to incrementally build the code,
   2.1. is there a way to use Python 2.6 distutils or
   2.2. is it possible to alter the Python 2.7 distuils package?

Comment: Are you sure it's rebuilding?  `python setup.py --help build` shows that there is a `-f` option to "forcably build (ignore timestamps)" which doesn't seem like it should exist if that is the default behavior...

Comment: @mgilson It is defiantly rebuilding everything. Maybe it is some setting in the `setup.py` script itself? Although, if it is there I cannot find it...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that.  Compiled .o files were reused in a simplistic and buggy way, so this optimization was removed in 2.7.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue5372 for details.

Comment: Thx for this answer! But I was looking more in a direction of: How do I tweak python 2.7 distutils to overwrite the new "non-buggy" way which rebuilds all .o files by default. Is there an option flag I could pass or do I have to dig into the code to make the code not recompile all the code files to create new .o files?

Comment: Well, my point was to tell that you can’t do that, and you should not try to, because of the problem I mention.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your exact problem, but I have had a similar issue that I fixed by the following method:

I have a relatively large C++ package with a python wrapper based on cython.  What I ended up doing was compiling the package to a static library using CMake (which does incremental builds), and then linking in the static library with the cython wrapper - which is pretty stable, though it is recompiled every time for safety's sake.  My setup.py is hacked in order to accept some flags that tell CMake what to do.

The relevant snippet from my setup.py that deals with the CMake part (https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp/blob/master/wrappers/Python/setup.py) looks like:

```
# ******************************
#       CMAKE OPTIONS
# ******************************

# Example using CMake to build static library:
# python setup.py install --cmake-compiler vc9 --cmake-bitness 64

if '--cmake-compiler' in sys.argv:
    i = sys.argv.index('--cmake-compiler')
    sys.argv.pop(i)
    cmake_compiler = sys.argv.pop(i)
else:
    cmake_compiler = ''

if '--cmake-bitness' in sys.argv:
    i = sys.argv.index('--cmake-bitness')
    sys.argv.pop(i)
    cmake_bitness = sys.argv.pop(i)
else:
    cmake_bitness = ''

USING_CMAKE = cmake_compiler or cmake_bitness

cmake_config_args = []
cmake_build_args = ['--config','"Release"']
STATIC_LIBRARY_BUILT = False
if USING_CMAKE:

    # Always force build since any changes in the C++ files will not force a rebuild
    touch('CoolProp/CoolProp.pyx')

    if 'clean' in sys.argv:
        if os.path.exists('cmake_build'):
            print('removing cmake_build folder...')
            shutil.rmtree('cmake_build')
            print('removed.')

    if cmake_compiler == 'vc9':
        if cmake_bitness == '32':
            generator = ['-G','"Visual Studio 9 2008"']
        elif cmake_bitness == '64':
            generator = ['-G','"Visual Studio 9 2008 Win64"']
        else:
            raise ValueError('cmake_bitness must be either 32 or 64; got ' + cmake_bitness)
    elif cmake_compiler == 'vc10':
        if cmake_bitness == '32':
            generator = ['-G','"Visual Studio 10 2010"']
        elif cmake_bitness == '64':
            generator = ['-G','"Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64"']
        else:
            raise ValueError('cmake_bitness must be either 32 or 64; got ' + cmake_bitness)
    else:
        raise ValueError('cmake_compiler [' + cmake_compiler + '] is invalid')

    cmake_build_dir = os.path.join('cmake_build', '{compiler}-{bitness}bit'.format(compiler=cmake_compiler, bitness=cmake_bitness))
    if not os.path.exists(cmake_build_dir):
        os.makedirs(cmake_build_dir)
    subprocess.check_call(' '.join(['cmake','../../../..','-DCOOLPROP_STATIC_LIBRARY=ON']+generator+cmake_config_args), shell = True, stdout = sys.stdout, stderr = sys.stderr, cwd = cmake_build_dir)
    subprocess.check_call(' '.join(['cmake','--build', '.']+cmake_build_args), shell = True, stdout = sys.stdout, stderr = sys.stderr, cwd = cmake_build_dir)

    # Now find the static library that we just built
    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        static_libs = []
        for search_suffix in ['Release/*.lib','Release/*.a', 'Debug/*.lib', 'Debug/*.a']:
            static_libs += glob.glob(os.path.join(cmake_build_dir,search_suffix))

    if len(static_libs) != 1:
        raise ValueError("Found more than one static library using CMake build.  Found: "+str(static_libs))
    else:
        STATIC_LIBRARY_BUILT = True
        static_library_path = os.path.dirname(static_libs[0])
```